# Is it possible to #Include in a "diamond inheritance" structure?

Tags: c, include

I'm trying to make some project in C.

I would like to know if it is possible to make `#include` from the same file twice, in a way that recalls diamond heritage.

i.e.

- in **a.c** there is `#include "a.h"`
- in **b.c** there is `#include "b.h"`
- in **b.h** there is `#include "a.h"`

Is it possible to `#include "b.h"` in **a.c**?

I get an error:

```
some_variable already defined in a.obj
```

Comment: Simple: don't *define* variables in headers, just *declare* them.

Comment: @PaulR how do you declare `int` in header without defining it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple: don't *define* variables in headers, just *declare* them:

Header:

```
// a.h

#ifndef A_H             // always use #include guards
#define A_H

extern int my_variable; // declare my_variable

...

#endif
```

Source file a.c:

```
// a.c

#include "a.h"

int my_variable;        // define my_variable

...
```

Source file b.c:

```
// a.c

#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

...
```

As others have mentioned, #include guards are useful, and a good habit to get into, but they are probably not the solution for this specific problem.

Comment: I already use the "#include guards", It doesn't help, I'll try your solution

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare `extern` the variables in **a.h**, then modify your header **a.h** in the following way:

```
 #ifndef a_h
 #define a_h

   //your a.h 

 #endif
```